# Upsert removes field if it's not in the new document

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, upsert

Let's assume the following model (note `strict:false`):

```
var Test = db.model('Test', {
  a: {type: String, required: true},
  b: {type: String}
}, {strict: false});
```

and I currently have this document in the database:

```
{
  'a': 'hello',
  'b': 'world',
  'c': {
       'x': 'embedded',
       'z': 'document' 
     }
}
```

If I `upsert` the following document:

```
doc = {
  'a': 'hello',
  'b': 'jack'
}
```

with something like:

```
Test.findOneAndUpdate({
  a: 'hello'
}, doc, {upsert:true}, function(){});
```

I will end up with:

```
{
  'a': 'hello',
  'b': 'jack'
}
```

In other words, a field `c` that is not present in the upserted document is wiped.

How can I safely upsert without wiping such fields?

Answer (score 0):

Strange, this should work as is. Maybe you can try explicitly setting fields:

```
doc = {$set: {
  'a': 'hello',
  'b': 'jack'
}};
```

Comment: Unfortunately that's not really feasible, because of the `strict:false`, I often have unpredictable field names in my data.